# how to export java desktop application which uses database to other pcs?

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I made a java desktop application on netbeans in which i used Mysql database.Now i want to export this application to other computers in a way that the user only use application and that user doesn't have mysql. is it necessary that the user should have Mysql? is there any other options which meet my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL needs to be executed in some way, so I can only think in:

1. The user needs to have MySQL installed
2. You host a MySQL server for all users to connect to
3. You develop a way to install MySQL automatically (I don't know of anybody that went this route, probably is too difficult)
4. You replace the usage of MySQL in your application with one embedded database engine, such as HSQLDB, Derby or others, that can be distributed with it and can create a database on demand.

An [embedded database comparison](http://lightjavadatabase.blogspot.co.uk/).